# Define "greater than" for nats in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I believe I have the less than(lt) function correct, but I'm not sure what to do with the greater than(gte)

```
lt :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
lt Z     (S b) = True
lt (S a) (S b) = lt a b

gte :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool
gte Z     b = False
gte (S a) b =
```

Comment: `gte` usually stands for "greater than or equal to", not "greater than".

Comment: Remark: Your `lt` is partial. Try `lt Z Z` or `lt (S Z) Z`.

Comment: You're right. It is greater than or equal too.

Comment: When I tried `lt Z Z` or `lt (S Z)  Z` I received this error `Non-exhaustive patterns in function lt`. Do I need to add conditions for these cases as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to cover all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Nat` is defined like this:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

so to define a function `f :: Nat -> ...` you have to specify what happens to both constructors:

```
f Z     = ...
f (S a) = ...
```

Likewise, for a function of two `Nat` variables, you have to consider the four possible combinations of constructors:

```
g Z     Z     = ...
g Z     (S a) = ...
g (S a) Z     = ...
g (S a) (S b) = ...
```

It might turn out that you can combine some of theses cases, but this is a good way to start out on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the fact that `A >= B` is the same as `not (A < B)`, since you have already implemented `lt`?